# DNS with authentication?

Tags: networking, dns

To get my DNS to allow forwards from my home network was easy, just enter the static ip in "trusted".

But my laptop don't have a static ip, as I bring it with me, and it gets DHCP-addresses from the networks i visit.

So what alternatives do I have to be able to use it as my default dns server from my laptop.
So far I have 2 ides, but I hope you have more/better ideas.

- Manually add the IP from the networks I visit.
- Allow forward-dns from any ip.

(Have settings for .test and .localhost on my DNS server, so want to use it as my default dns-server.)

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to  move your server everywhere and have it be accessible from the internet, or is it only for local visits from inside the network? If its the latter, don't forget, your computer has a computername too (aka hostname) which binds to whatever ip address is being assigned to you. People can just `http://computername` in their browser to visit your webserver.

Comment: You might want to modify the title.  "DNS with authentication" has  a whole other meaning to the one you mean, and involves a MUCH more complex set of technologies irrelevant here. (zone signing)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't be running an open resolver (option 2) without extensive experience in DNS server operation. Open DNS resolvers can cause all kinds of problems when abused by malicious parties (DNS amplification attacks). You probably don't want to get into that for an easy solution.

Option 1 is quite cumbersome. However, if you add an authentication layer that allows access to your DNS server (like a VPN or a tunnel), then you don't have to bother with the IP administration. You could also create a web service with authentication to change your firewall dynamically.

The best option, for the constraints given, in my opinion would be to run a slave DNS server on your laptop. Every time you connect to your home network it would get the latest version of the zone files and cache them for local use. You would only have to change the forwarder addresses dynamically based on DHCP. You could script something with Bind or use dnsmasq, which has these features built-in.

The actual best option would be to get a domain name and run your own DNS server (authorative, not forwarding/resolving), and host the records there (`hostname.test.puggan.com` or something). You could use search paths to make sure you don't have to type the whole FQDN (so you only type `hostname.test` and it will look for `hostname.test.puggan.com`).